# Python3.4 int object is not iterable - MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm running python3.4 and i'm trying to run a query with the MySQLdb library.

I've done one successful query but now I am stuck when it comes to integers in a query. Here's the code:

```
                location = player_info[6]

                query2 = ("SELECT name FROM locations WHERE id=%d");
                execute = cursor.execute(query2, (location));
```

Value of the variable location is 2. I just keep getting the error:

> File "login.py", line 75, in tryLogin
>       execute = cursor.execute(query2, (location));
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 195, in
>   execute
>       args = tuple(map(db.literal, args)) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I tried to change the %d to %s because someone said it should all be in string format but I still get the same error.

I have also tried changing "location" variable to simply:

location = 2

Any ideas?

Comment: There's an example here that uses a number.  http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples

Comment: What happend to your other comment? Where should I put the questionmark???????   ??  ?? ?

Comment: I was thinking of PreparedStatements in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            execute = cursor.execute(query2, (location));
```

In python, `(location)` is a parenthesized expression, not a tuple.  In order to force that to be a tuple, you need to add a comma: `(location,)`

```
            execute = cursor.execute(query2, (location,));
```